# iText 7 pdfHTML extension doesn't implement all of my CSS when converting my html to pdf in my C# utility

Tags: c#, itext7, pdfhtml

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .styled-table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 25px 0;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            min-width: 400px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            width: 100%;
        }

        .styled-table thead tr {
            background-color: #004298;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .styled-table th,
        .styled-table td {
            padding: 12px 15px;
        }

        .styled-table tbody tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }

        .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
        }

        .styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #004298;
        }

        .styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #004298;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class='styled-table'>
        <thead>
            <tr class='active-row'>
                <th>Allowed access control list</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr class='active-row'>
            <td>
                <table class='styled-table'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>172.16.40.250 - Blue Coat SG-VA Series>show allowed-access</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>192.168.1.69 255.255.255.255</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>192.168.1.71 255.255.255.255</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    <table class='styled-table'>
        <thead>
            <tr class='active-row'>
                <th>Proxy Client and Unified Agent settings</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr class='active-row'>
            <td>
                <table class='styled-table'>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>172.16.40.250 - Blue Coat SG-VA Series>show clients</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>Client Manager configuration</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Activation </strong></td>
                        <td> disabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Host </strong></td>
                        <td> from client request</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Install Port </strong></td>
                        <td> 8084</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Keyring </strong></td>
                        <td> default</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Manager Version </strong></td>
                        <td> 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> PxC Software Upgrade URL </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> PxC Archive Version </strong></td>
                        <td> 3.4.3.2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> PxC MSI file size </strong></td>
                        <td> 10951680 bytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> PxC BSX file size </strong></td>
                        <td> 9668837 bytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> UA Software Upgrade URL </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> UA Archive Version </strong></td>
                        <td> 4.7.1.188819</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> UA32 MSI file size </strong></td>
                        <td> 4939776 bytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> UA64 MSI file size </strong></td>
                        <td> 6496256 bytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> UA OSX ZIP file size </strong></td>
                        <td> 11663933 bytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Update Interval </strong></td>
                        <td> 120 minutes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Uninstall Password </strong></td>
                        <td> Disabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>Client Manager Web-filter configuration</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Activation </strong></td>
                        <td> disabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Safe Search </strong></td>
                        <td> disabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> HTTPS Filtering </strong></td>
                        <td> enabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Default Action </strong></td>
                        <td> allow</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Failure Mode </strong></td>
                        <td> closed</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'> Log Settings </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Activation </strong></td>
                        <td> enabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Log </strong></td>
                        <td> all</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Early upload </strong></td>
                        <td> 50 megabytes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Periodic upload </strong></td>
                        <td> 24 hrs 0 minutes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'> Primary FTP Server </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Host </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Port </strong></td>
                        <td> 21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Path </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'> Alternate FTP Server </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Host </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Port </strong></td>
                        <td> 21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Path </strong></td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'> List of Selected Categories and Actions</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>Locations</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> Webfilter </strong></td>
                        <td> Enabled</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'> Locations List</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
</body>

</html>
```

I call the following method in my C# code:

```
public void createPdf(string html, string dest)
{
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
}
```

The converted PDF ignores most of the CSS directives.  I tried this on iText's online converter and get the same results.
The HTML looks like this:
[image: image of HTML]

The converted PDF looks like this:
[image: image of converted HTML to PDF]

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to fix?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @KJ, but why is the sans-serif font not being respected?  Secondly, is it worth applying styling inline?

Comment: `box-shadow` is not supported by pdfHTML. As a workaround for the problem with blue bottom borders you can try replacing `.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type` -> `.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type>td`. `.styled-table tbody tr.active-row` does not seem to be used (at least in PDF conversion context) so you can drop it. With those small fixes you can get a much better result already. pdfHTML is not perfect but it's improving!